# Issue on javascript regex matching with match function

Tags: javascript, regex, match

`'C12345678'.match("^C\d{8}$")` and

```
'C12345678'.match("^C\[0-9]{8}$")
```

Why does this statement has different values?

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first case you need to escape the backslash:

```js
   console.log('C12345678'.match("^C\\d{8}$"));
```

#### Edit

As pointed out by Wiktor in the comment below, it's best to use the Regex literal syntax:

```js
    console.log('C12345678'.match(/^C\d{8}$/));
```

Comment: Best is `/^C\d{8}$/` since it is readable, does not require using double backslashes to escape special characters and because the pattern is static.